# Serializing Object as JSON String Instead of JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

I am working on writing a client library for reading from an MQTT API (that I have no control over).

For making requests I have a helper Request class that has all the default request parameters that always need to be provided. Each request has a payload property. I implemented this by making the Request class a generic class like: `public class Request<T> where T : IRequestPayload` and that has worked great, with one exception, when the request payload is only a string. Since string doesn't implement IRequestPayload, I cant make a Request with a payload of type string.

While looking into ways to handle this I wondered if it would be possible to flatten a derived Request class's Value property and save it to Payload. An example of what I mean is below:

Classes:

```cs
public interface IPayload { }

public interface IRequestPayload : IPayload { }

public abstract class Request<T> where T : IRequestPayload {
    public T? Payload { get; set; } = null;
}

public class MyAPIRequestPayload : IRequestPayload {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyAPIRequest : Request<MyAPIRequestPayload> {
}
```

Desired JSON Input/Output:

```json
{
    "Payload":"MyValue"
}
```

Desired object values:

- MyAPIRequest.Payload = instanceof(MyAPIRequestPayload)
- MyAPIRequestPayload.Value = "MyValue"

Edit:
Added in the payload marker interfaces.

Comment: Can you show what `IRequestPayload` looks like; is it just a marker interface?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? It is a widely used library for json serialization/deserialization.

Comment: It looks like you need `public class MyAPIRequestPayload : Request<T>, IRequestPayload { public override string Value { get; set; } }`

Comment: You want your payload to be an object with a _payload_ property that holds an _string value_, and when mapping to an object in your client this needs to be mapped to a class with a property of type ```T``` ```where T : IRequestPayload```, and also __T__ needs to have an inner property __Value__ of type string?

Comment: you can implement a generic `IRequestPayload<T>` and use it with `Request<T>`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils it is a marker interface that extends IPayload that is another marker interface.

Comment: @itectori I just briefly looked at the docs for it and it supports TypeConverter which may work for what I'm looking for. I will need to check on that.

Comment: @RigobertoRamirezCruz Not quite (If I am understanding what you are saying). I want to have a Request object that has a Payload property of type T. This payload then has a member property Value of type string. Then when I got to serialize/deserialize the Payload, I want it to be converted to/from a string who's value goes into the Value property.